# Looking for LINQ syntax that gets the second item in a list that starts with something specific

Tags: c#, list, linq

Using the code below, I can get the first item in a list that starts with "5VOH".

```
list.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("5VOH"));
```

How can i get the 2nd or 3rd? I've tried using...

```
list.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("5VOH"));
```

But that isn't working. It's still grabbing the first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing is skipping the first item regardless of whether it matches your filter.  Instead you want to filter then skip 1 then take the first one after that or the default if there isn't a second match.

```
var results = list.Where(s => s.StartsWith("5VOH")).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Use Skip(1) to skip 1st.

```
list.Where(s => s.StartsWith("5VOH")).Skip(1).FirstOrDefaoult();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could write a function to get any N-th element.

Here N is 0-based but you could make it whatever you like.

```
    public static string FindNthItem(List<string> list, string search, int n)
    {
        var results = list.Where(x => x.StartsWith(search)).ToList();
        if (n > results.Count || n < 0)
            return null;
        else
            return results[n];
    }
```

Comment: You need to compare `n` to the number of items in the result or you can get an exception from using `ElementAt`.  To avoid multiple passes on the `result` it would be better to just do `return list.Where(x => x.StartsWith(search)).Skip(n).FirstOrDefault();`  Maybe add a check if `n` is less than 0 too.

Comment: Yes actually I meant to say `results.Count`, not `list.Count`, my mistake.

Comment: Since `results` is an `IEnumerable<string>` you need to use `Count()` or better yet throw a `ToList` after the `Where` so results will be a `List<string>` and you will avoid the double iteration.  Also can use `results[n]` then instead of `ElementAt(n)`.